# How to do jQuery border a Bootstrap card onclick?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm newbie to Bootstrap. I wish to highlight a clicked card with jQuery by an onclick event. But dont really know how to do. This is my cards and the picture of my cards. So i would love to have a correct way to hold a green border to the selected card one:

I wrote these lines below in order to highlight the card, add a border class to it, and then show it on html. But it doesn't work:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#card').select();
});

$('card').addClass('border').value('green');
$('card').click(function() {
  $('#card border').html('show');
});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <center>
    <h6>My cards below</h6>
  </center>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div type="button" id="card_0" class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-xl-0 mb-4" name="card_title_0" onclick="highlight(this)">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header p-3 pt-2">
            <div class="icon icon-lg icon-shape bg-gradient-dark shadow-dark text-center border-radius-xl mt-n4 position-absolute">
              <i class="material-icons opacity-10">login</i>
            </div>
            <div class="text-end pt-1">
              <p class="text-sm mb-0 text-capitalize">card_title_0</p>
              <h4 class="mb-0">card_value_0</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr class="dark horizontal my-0">
          <div class="card-footer p-3">
            <p class="mb-0"><span class="text-success text-sm font-weight-bolder">card_percent_0 % </span> actuellement
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div type="button" id="card_1" class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-xl-0 mb-4" name="card_title_1" onclick="highlight(this)">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header p-3 pt-2">
            <div class="icon icon-lg icon-shape bg-gradient-primary shadow-primary text-center border-radius-xl mt-n4 position-absolute">
              <i class="material-icons opacity-10">person</i>
            </div>
            <div class="text-end pt-1">
              <p class="text-sm mb-0 text-capitalize">card_title_1</p>
              <h4 class="mb-0">card_value_1</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr class="dark horizontal my-0">
          <div class="card-footer p-3">
            <p class="mb-0"><span class="text-success text-sm font-weight-bolder">card_percent_1 % </span> since now</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div type="button" id="card_2" class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-xl-0 mb-4" name="card_title_2" onclick="highlight(this)">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header p-3 pt-2">
            <div class="icon icon-lg icon-shape bg-gradient-info shadow-info text-center border-radius-xl mt-n4 position-absolute">
              <i class="material-icons opacity-10">person</i>
            </div>
            <div class="text-end pt-1">
              <p class="text-sm mb-0 text-capitalize">card_title_2</p>
              <h4 class="mb-0">card_value_2</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr class="dark horizontal my-0">
          <div class="card-footer p-3">
            <p class="mb-0"><span class="text-danger text-sm font-weight-bolder">card_percent_2 %</span> since now</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div type="button" id="card_3" class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-xl-0 mb-4" name="card_title_3" onclick="highlight(this)">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header p-3 pt-2">
            <div class="icon icon-lg icon-shape bg-gradient-success shadow-success text-center border-radius-xl mt-n4 position-absolute">
              <i class="material-icons opacity-10">person</i>
            </div>
            <div class="text-end pt-1">
              <p class="text-sm mb-0 text-capitalize">card_title_3</p>
              <h4 class="mb-0">card_value_3</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr class="dark horizontal my-0">
          <div class="card-footer p-3">
            <p class="mb-0"><span class="text-success text-sm font-weight-bolder">card_percent_3% </span> since now</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are most likely missing a `.` in  `$('card')` || because `$('card')` would mean you are looking for a `<card>` element. Also again here you are missing something at border `$('#card border')`

Comment: `$('#card').tab();` would not target anything, because you don't have any element with the id of card

Comment: Always **check your selectors** - add `console.log($("card").length)` and look in the browser console (F12).  If it's zero your selector is wrong or the element doesn't exist at the time the code runs.

Comment: I've change ` $('card') ` to this ` $('.card') ` and far change ` $('#card') ` to this one ` $('#card_0') ` but it doesn't make my borderline appear. Have you a better approach to give?

Comment: ``$('.card').addClass('border').value('green');`` is causing an error, because a DIV has no value. What do you want to achieve with ``.value('green')``?

Comment: @biberman, I just try that to set border-color to green. I don't really know how to do it

Comment: you could instead use ``.css({"border-color": "green"})``...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also not very skilled with Bootstrap 4. I would do it like this:

```
$('.card').on('click', function (e) {
  $('.card').css('border-color', '')
  $(this).css('border-color', 'green')
});
```

The first line remove the border color on all cards. The second line set the border color to green on the clicked card.